# Accordion show effect: 'none' not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion where I am on create defaulting to the second section(or tab).

When the page loads, the accordion animates the section section to open. I do not want it to animate, I want it to just show.

Here is my initialize

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    show: { effect: "none"},
    create: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('#accordion').accordion("option", "active", 2);
    }
});
```

I have tried setting the show property to `'none'`. The animation is still occurring. How can I remove the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example fiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/838/**

If you want to prevent the accordion animation, you should pass animate property as `false`.

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    animate: false,
    create: function(event, ui){
        $('#accordion').accordion("option", "active", 2);
    }
});
```

Comment: pardon me for not seeing animate property after being in the tab property sheet also this afternoon.